# Is it possible to make iptables on RHEL idempotent with Chef?

Tags: linux, configuration, centos, chef-infra, rhel

I want to enforce policy on the iptables of my system so that if someone were to manually make a change to iptables then Chef would bring it back into the proper state the next time it runs. Is this just a dream? One cookbook, a community cookbook called 'firewall', said that it would not be able to handle noticing if someone else added a firewall rule.

EDIT: To make things more clear: I am asking how to write an idempotent resource in Chef/Ruby that will be idempotent for iptables.

Comment: Also, what about just using the standard iptables tools to store and restore configuration? `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` are your friends.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is directly involving programming tools, it's about making iptables idempotent with Chef, as the question states. If you are unaware of what Chef is, it is a configuration management tool that uses Ruby.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added clarification. I am asking specifically how to write a Chef resource/Ruby code_block that will be idempotent. I edited the original post for clarification. The issue with your second comment is that doing so would require using Chef's execute resource which, by definition, is non-idempotent and stated in their documentation here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that makes a lot of sense; taking back my vote on this.

Comment: In order to make it truly idempotent, you'd have to write a parser for the output of iptables. In my experience, that gets messy really fast. It's easier to reset the entire ruleset, and re-apply, but you'll get a blip in traffic when you do it :(.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but I'm not aware of any cookbook that works in this way so you would have to write it. Check out some of Facebook's writeups about managed objects vs. managed collections in Chef, you will likely want to use the collections pattern for this.

This is generally not done because of how easy it is to accidentally "brick" a machine by disabling port 22, so make sure you put some special cases in for that, or have secondary access mechanisms in place like ILO et al.